# KiCad pin name to net name

Tags: kicad

Is there a method in KiCad to quickly map a pin name to a net label?

Example.

On the picture below, I want to name the wires with the pin names, as has already been done with `GND`. I'm currently doing this manually for each pin and am wondering if there is a smarter way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a patch floating around for that, but it's not finished, so it is doubtful it will be included in version 5.

Normally, I just label those pins where I'm not going to draw a wire, then I attach the label directly to the pin.

For GND, just attach the GND power symbol, which is a lot cleaner than actually connecting everything with wires -- same for the supply voltages. All power symbols with the same name are connected, same as all labels with the same name.